# Getting AttributeError when trying to create DynamoDB table with global index using boto v2.25.0

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am trying to create a DynamoDB table with a global secondary index following the example [**here**](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#low-level-api) (The `# The full, minimum-extra-calls case.` block under `class boto.dynamodb2.table.Table...`). I am using `boto` version 2.25.0. The exact code is:

```
import boto
from boto import dynamodb2
table = boto.dynamodb2.table.Table('myTable', 
       schema=[HashKey('firstKey')], 
       throughput={'read':5,'write':2},
       global_indexes=[GlobalAllIndex('secondKeyIndex',parts=[HashKey('secondKey')],throughput={'read':5,'write':3})], 
       connection=dynamodb2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id=<MYID>,aws_secret_access_key=<MYKEY>))
```

I am getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'table'`

What am I doing wrong?

======

EDIT: Based on Jharrod's answer below, here's the final version of the code:

```
import os
import boto
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table, HashKey, GlobalAllIndex
table = Table.create('myTable', 
    schema=[HashKey('firstKey')], 
    throughput={'read':5,'write':2},
    global_indexes=[GlobalAllIndex('secondKeyIndex',parts=[HashKey('secondKey')],throughput={'read':5,'write':3})], 
    connection=boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id=<MYID>,aws_secret_access_key=<MYKEY>))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying importing it this way:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
```

I've written a library that can do this as well, on top of botocore: [PynamoDB](https://github.com/jlafon/pynamodb).

Comment: Thanks. When using an older version of `boto` without GSI, I had the following sequence of statements: `import boto... conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(... table = conn.create_table(... table.refresh(wait_for_active=True)`. Do you know if there is something similar to `refresh` in the new library?