# DynamoDB OrderBy operation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
Table : Customer

Item: CustomerId,PurchaseType,Name,mobilenumber,price, createdDate

DATA1: cus001,"online","BBBBB","yourmobilenumber",6000,"01/07/2017 01:12:05"
DATA2: cus002,"online","myname","mymobilenumber",500,"10/07/2017 01:12:01"
DATA3: cus003,"online","AAAAA","yourmobilenumber",6000,"10/07/2017 01:12:06"
DATA4: cus004,"online","yourname","yourmobilenumber",1000,"10/07/2017 02:12:06"
DATA5: cus005,"retail","yourname","yourmobilenumber",1000,"10/07/2017 03:12:06"
```

GSI: price-index[PurchaseType,price]

Query with index "price-index"

condition: purchasetype="online" and price >500

ScanIndex: true

How to get the result based on the following conditions:

purchasetype="online"
price>500
order by Name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamodb scan in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794945/dynamodb-scan-in-sorted-order)

Comment: what is the partition and sort key of price-index ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a different **GSI**:

**PurchaseType** - partition key of the GSI

**Name** - sort key of the GSI

Then you can use a query to find all items with the necessary purchase type, order by Name and provide a [filter expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) to filter all items with high prices.