# How to sort data from dynamo DB using nodeJS in AWS-lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am retrieving data from the table using onScan in lambda function. I want to sort them based on the timestamp. Please advise on this

```
var params = {
    TableName: "LogEvents",
    FilterExpression: "#Environment = :env",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
       "#Environment": "Environment",
    }   
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [dynamodb-scan-in-sorted-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794945/dynamodb-scan-in-sorted-order)

Answer (score 1):

Hope following example will help you.

```
var params = {
        TableName: "Table",
         IndexName: "DataID-Created-index",
          KeyConditionExpression: "DataID = :v_ID AND 
         Created > :v_created",
         ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_ID": {S: "some_id"},
                            ":v_created": {N: "timestamp"}
    },
      ProjectionExpression: "ID, DataID, Created, Data"
   };


  ddb.query(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) 
          console.log(err);
      else {
           data.Items.sort(function(a, b) {
             return parseFloat(a.Created.N) - 
       parseFloat(b.Created.N);
            });
         // More code here
        }
       });
```

Comment: Here v_created is the column_name. Am i rite ?

Comment: Yes its columns name