# Get data from DynamoDB sorted by timestamp

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have the attached data structure in my DynamoDB table. `to` is the PartitionKey, `from` is the sort key. I use the following Python Lambda function to retrieve all my data. The problem I currently face is that the response results are not sorted by timestamp (new to old).

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.scan()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response['Items']
    }
```

DynamoDB table structure

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
|    to     |   from    |   medium   |  messageBody  | timestamp |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| 123456789 | 1234:4321 | somemedium | Hello World 1 |  23422523 |
| 123456789 | 9876:4321 | somemedium | Hello World 2 |  23432529 |
| 123456789 | 4565:3213 | somemedium | Hello World 3 |  23467839 |
| 123456789 | 4565:3323 | somemedium | Hello World 4 |  23533789 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Update:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

import logging
import json
import decimal


## Set logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

## Set DynamoDB
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("MyTable")

logger.info(f"CREATED NEW ITEM IN DYANMODB")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.query(
        IndexName='to-timestamp-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('to').eq(12345)
    )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response['Items']
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `table.scan()` which does not guarantee any ordering. You can create  a new secondary  index with timestamp as the `sort/range` key. After that, use `query` (instead of a scan) on that secondary index to retrieve the results sorted on the range key.

Related question [Dynamodb scan in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794945/dynamodb-scan-in-sorted-order)

Comment: Hi Rubbal, I adjusted my code in Python (see updated). However, I always get `"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter KeyConditionExpression, value: <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Key object at 0x7f8fe8dbdaf0>, type: <class 'boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Key'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I believe I solved it now with `KeyConditionExpression=Key('to').eq(12345),`

Answer (score 0):

Create a **secondary index** `to-timestamp-index` using `to` as PartitionKey and `timestamp` as SortKey, then in the query set

> "IndexName":'to-timestamp-index',
> "ScanIndexForward": false

This will sort your items from newest to oldest. If you wanted to sort from oldest to newest, you would set the `ScanIndexForward` property to `true`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34501311)